# Use of inverse in defining Lebesgue measure

Tags: lebesgue-measure, inverse-function, measurable-functions, measurable-sets

Reading literature on the development of the Lebesgue integral, I encountered statements similar to this:
Let $$E_i=\{x\in [a,b]: y_i\leq f(x) \leq y_{i+1}\} = f^{-1}([y_j, y_{j+1})) $$
I understand the first part (set of all points x corresponding to a slice of the function range). What confuses me is the use of the inverse. Does the second part imply the function f is required to be invertible on the given interval? Or is this a different notion of "inverse"?

Comment: It is ambiguous notation. In this context, $f^{-1}(A) = \{ x | f(x) \in A \}$.

Comment: Thanks, I am relieved!

Comment: It's a "set theoretical" inverse. Maps sets to sets, not points to points.